# Axios post request on proxy in create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, axios

so I have this in my package.json proxy in create-react-app:

```
"proxy": "http://www.myapi.com"
```

my post requests works on other routes:

```
axios.post('/v1/users', { // http://www.myapi.com/v1/users
            email: email,
            password: password
        })
        .then((response) => { 
            this.setState((state, props) => ({
                registrationSuccess: true
            }));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.setState((state, props) => ({
                registrationError: true
            }));
        });
```

but when I want to make post request on root, this works on postman, like on http://www.myapi.com it fails, this fails:

```
 axios.post('/', { // http://www.myapi.com
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
```

it will make post request on localhost:3000/, but I want to make post request on proxy. help?

Comment: any solution to this?